# Creating a web page on Github

Tags: html, jsp, github

I'm creating a page on github. In the "setting" I have selected the page option "master branch".

I found out that my site's url is automatically redirecting to "index.html" file in the repository, but actually I would like my site url to show "main.jsp"

So I have created "index.html" file like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=main.jsp'>
<title>CafeGO</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I enter the url, jus the "main.jsp" file is downloaded, not redirected.
How can I solve this problem? :'(

I have also tried this way (index.html) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
location.href="main.jsp";
</script>
```

Comment: I think JSP only works on tomcat. Your code is fine. maybe use location.redirect()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the GitHub [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-github-pages/)

> GitHub Pages is a static site hosting service and doesn't support server-side code such as, PHP, Ruby, or Python.

As JavaServer Pages are dynamic GitHub pages do not support them.